# CSS Layout Ajustment

Tags: html, css

I´ve recently started to program all my layouts in tableless CSS, but still prefering the old tables style. Much faster. Anyway, I´m stuck in this layout that is almoust finished, but I need help to one minor detais, which I can´t manage to fix.

Here is the test address:
http://www.syncsystem.com.br/

As you can see, the design and background are almoust complete. Later I´m gonna put the rest of the stuff in, like links and so on. The problem is at the bottom. The ideia behind this is that the background texture stay fixed, as is is. But there´s a white space at the bottom which I can´t get rid of...can anyone help or give a hint?

Thanks,

Comment: The white background you're seeing is the body element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you are talking about, but the footer's [background image](http://www.syncsystem.com.br/en/img/FundoSiteBottom01.png) itself has some space in it below the black part.
And the footer has the same height as it's background image, so the whole image is being shown.

Next time use some web development tool such as [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), or use a native one pressing F12 in Firefox or Chrome. It will help you quickly analyze the page element's properties

Comment: Yeah, it has, but in my view, it shouldn´t add space after it, because it´s inside the <div class="Conteiner01">. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Hey, it seems like there was another control (asp.net) inside the page that was messing it up. It had a height defined to 100%. It seems to be working fine now. But thanks anyway for the tip about the firebug...I´m gonna intall it here and try to use it on future projects...